# Should we create [payara] and [payara-micro] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

[Payara](http://www.payara.fish/home) is a "supported build of GlassFish".

There are already tags for [glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glassfish), [glassfish-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glassfish-3), [glassfish-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glassfish-4), [glassfish-4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glassfish-4.1) etc., but no "payara" tag yet, despite some questions which I think need a separate tag:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221153/apache-camel-cxf-include-in-a-maven-solution-does-not-deploy-on-glassfish-payara
- [Deploy Java EE application to payara41 docker container using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272081/deploy-java-ee-application-to-payara41-docker-container-using-maven)
- [What are environment properties for Payara InitialContext from free standing Java Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33114983/what-are-environment-properties-for-payara-initialcontext-from-free-standing-jav)
- [How do I add JDBC drivers and configure JDBC Resources in Payara Micro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899120/how-do-i-add-jdbc-drivers-and-configure-jdbc-resources-in-payara-micro)

On the one hand, Payara is built to be a "drop-in replacement for GlassFish", meaning that they are, by design, as similar as possible, but on the other hand there are a number of extra features added to Payara which have nothing to do with GlassFish.

I would suggest that the following two tags are created:

- [payara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payara)
- [payara-micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payara-micro)

I don't think there's any need for a version tag like there is with GlassFish.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Payara. Not sure if that's necessary information, but there it is.

Comment: Is there a significant enough difference between `payara` and `payara-micro` to justify two tags, or can the same result be made by combining the tags `payara` and `glassfish` or `payara` and `glassfish-embedded`? Side note: Disclosing your affiliation is appreciated.

Comment: Well, the tags now exist. Please provide tag-excerpt and tag-wiki complying with the guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts Avoid being overly promotional, we are not a bill board. Take care to clearly show the differences between payara / payara-micro / glassfish and glassfish-embedded, and in the excerpt when to use which.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I've added to the tag-wikis for both if you want to check them over: [payara](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/payara/info) | [payara-micro](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/payara-micro/info) (they still need to be peer reviewed anyway)

Comment: I wonder how long it will take before a tag merge will be requested. It is exactly worded on the Payara site that Payara IS a drop-in replacement for Glassfish, I don't see why you need a specific tag for it. People will likely just choose to tag both to not have to think what is relevant or not, and to reach the complete target audience.

Comment: Payara is both a drop in replacement and also has additional features. GlassFish comes with a default "domain1" and Payara maintains compatibility with that, but adds extra features in a separate "payaradomain". E.g. there isn't a finalised JCache implementation in GlassFish, so Payara have chosen to use Hazelcast to provide that. There **is** a lot of crossover, but I think the differences are significant enough. (especially with Payara Micro, which is very different)

Comment: Well the tag is there, now time will tell how well it works out :)